# Filling a TSQL query with NULL coming from an html form

Tags: php, sql, forms, t-sql, null

I have an html page with a form that contains a couple of selectors.

The form is processed by GET via a js function that uses jquery ajax to send the data to a php page. 
The php builds the TSQL query to select the information.

If you don’t choose any option in the selectors I need a NULL in my query. 
Both in the js and php page I’ve tried with:

```
if($variableFromSelector1 ==’-’){ $variableFromSelector1 =’NULL’;}
if($variableFromSelector2 ==’-’){ $variableFromSelector2 =’NULL’;}
```

(the – means nothing chosen in the selector)

But this fills the query with ‘NULL’ which is not the same as NULL

Here's how the query goes:

```
   function showData($variableFromSelector1,$variableFromSelector2)
    {  

            $strSqlSelect = "EXECUTE mybd.dbo.myprocedure 
            @var1='".$variableFromSelector1."',
            @var2='".$variableFromSelector2."'";
    }
```

How can I get the query with NULL in case no option is chosen in the selector?

Thanks a lot

Comment: how are you building your query?

Comment: syntax error if I do $var = NULL

Comment: edited my post so you can see the query. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($variableFromSelector1 ==’-’){ $variableFromSelector1 = NULL;}
if($variableFromSelector2 ==’-’){ $variableFromSelector2 = NULL;}

function showData($variableFromSelector1,$variableFromSelector2)
{  
  $var1 = is_null($variableFromSelector1) ? 'NULL' : "'{$variableFromSelector1}'";
  $var2 = is_null($variableFromSelector2) ? 'NULL' : "'{$variableFromSelector2}'";

  $strSqlSelect = "EXECUTE mybd.dbo.myprocedure 
  @var1=".$var1.",
  @var2=".$var2;
}
```

Also remember to sanitize all inputs to protect against SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

You're quoting `NULL` when you send it to your stored procedure. Try the following:

```
$strSqlSelect = "EXECUTE mybd.dbo.myprocedure 
@var1=" . ($variableFromSelector1 == '-' ? 'NULL' : "'{variableFromSelector1}'" . ",
@var2=" . ($variableFromSelector2 == '-' ? 'NULL' : "'{variableFromSelector2}'" . ";
```

Comment: Been trying yout suggestion but there are some syntax errors. I've detected so far the lack of ) but still working the rest out

Comment: See update. Looks like I missed some quotes. It's the ultimately the same as the other answer, just less code with the ternary operator.